# scanf from a generated string

Tags: c, string, scanf

I need to create a program to read a file line by line and in each line scan some data.
for example in a line like :

```
# 2 (x1,y1)(x2,y2)
```

i need x1,y1 and x2,y2
my code is

```
    char firstCharacter;
    char line[100];
    scanf("%c",&firstCharacter);
    while ((fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) && (line[0] != '\n')){
        if(firstCharacter == '#'){
            int nu_deadend;
            sscanf(line,"%d",&nu_deadend);
            for (int i = 0; i < nu_deadend; i++) {
                int x,y;
                sscanf(line,"(%d,%d)",&x,&y);
                printf("x: %d y: %d\n",x,y);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

but from input:

```
# 2 (2,3)(3,4)
```

it outputs:

```
x:0 y:0
x:0 y:0
```

expected output:

```
x:2 y:3
x:3 y:4
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Please state all the return values of scanf which yur code ignores.

Comment: Unlike `scanf` which continues where it left off, `sscanf` will start at the buffer it is given. So, you probably need to use (e.g.) `char *cp = line;` and then use and advance `cp` to point to the next token. `sscanf` is ill-suited to this. Better to use `fgets`, `cp`, and `strtok` and pass the return value of `strtok` to `sscanf` Also, you never reset `firstCharacter` for the second line (i.e. I presume each line starts with `#`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my top comment ...

Unlike `scanf` which continues where it left off, `sscanf` will start at the buffer it is given. So, you probably need to use (e.g.) `char *cp = line;` and then use and advance `cp` to point to the next token.

`sscanf` is ill-suited to this because it returns a *count* and *not* the number of bytes consumed.

Better to use `fgets`, `cp`, and `strtok` and pass the return value of `strtok` to `sscanf`

Also, you never reset `firstCharacter` for the second line (i.e. I presume each line starts with `#`)

---

Here is a refactored version. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)         printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)         do { } while (0)
#endif

int
main(void)
{
    char *tok;
    char line[100];

    // FORMAT:
    //  # <count> (x,y)(x,y)...
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) {
        dbgprt("LINE: %s",line);

        // get first token
        tok = strtok(line," \n");
        if (tok == NULL)
            break;

        // this must be "#"
        if (*tok != '#')
            continue;

        // get the count
        int nu_deadend;
        tok = strtok(NULL," \n");
        sscanf(tok, "%d", &nu_deadend);
        dbgprt("NUM: %d\n",nu_deadend);

        // get "(x,y)(x,y)(x,y)"
        tok = strtok(NULL," \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < nu_deadend; i++) {
            int x, y;

            dbgprt("TOK: '%s'\n",tok);
            sscanf(tok, "(%d,%d)", &x, &y);
            printf("x: %d y: %d\n", x, y);

            // advance past the end of the current (x,y)
            tok = strchr(tok,')');
            if (tok == NULL)
                break;
            ++tok;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the test input I used:

```
# 2 (2,3)(3,4)
# 3 (1,7)(9,2)(8,3)
```

---

Here is the debug output:

```
LINE: # 2 (2,3)(3,4)
NUM: 2
TOK: '(2,3)(3,4)'
x: 2 y: 3
TOK: '(3,4)'
x: 3 y: 4
LINE: # 3 (1,7)(9,2)(8,3)
NUM: 3
TOK: '(1,7)(9,2)(8,3)'
x: 1 y: 7
TOK: '(9,2)(8,3)'
x: 9 y: 2
TOK: '(8,3)'
x: 8 y: 3
```

And, here is the clean output:

```
x: 2 y: 3
x: 3 y: 4
x: 1 y: 7
x: 9 y: 2
x: 8 y: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the "#" from input. What is left in input (including the initial "2") is read into the buffer.

In contrast to the input stream, the string `line` you are using still contains the already successfully scanned initial "2" after `sscanf(line,"%d",&nu_deadend);`, instead of loosing it with a successful scan.

So your attempt to scan the "(...)" needs to take the "2" into account.

E.g. like

```
sscanf(line,"%*d (%d,%d)",&x,&y);
```

for the first "()".

The second one would either require more elaborate ignoring, or need to start scanning at an appropriate index for the relevant "(" inside the string.
Since you need to loop, the elaborate ignoring does not help. You will have to first search for the right "(" and then do the scanning.

Comment: What do you mean by "Other than the input stream"?

Comment: I edited. Is it clear now? @kirjosieppo

Comment: thank you for your response, I am actually new in c. how can I change the index to start scanning?

Comment: If you know the index of the appropriate "(" you can just add it to the `line`. For details please ask a separate question. Beter first check for existing similar questions.